# Child item event in PyQt5 QGraphicsItemGroup

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a graphic item group - 3 rectangles and text.

I want to make text editable, but cant. Focus is set on text, but still cant edit. Tried to set parent group to stop handling child events, but it doesnt work

```
class Uml(QGraphicsItemGroup):
def __init__(self, x, y, scene):
    super().__init__()
    self.setFiltersChildEvents(False)

    self.headerR = QGraphicsRectItem(x,y,70,30)
    self.header = QGraphicsTextItem("header")
    self.header.setPos(x,y)
    self.header.setTextInteractionFlags(Qt.TextEditorInteraction)

    self.attrR = QGraphicsRectItem(x, y+30,70,50)
    self.attr = QGraphicsTextItem("attributes")   
    self.attr.setPos(x,y+30)

    self.methodsR = QGraphicsRectItem(x, y+80,70,50)
    self.methods = QGraphicsTextItem("methods")   
    self.methods.setPos(x,y+80)
    
    self.addToGroup(self.headerR)
    self.addToGroup(self.header)
    self.addToGroup(self.attrR)
    self.addToGroup(self.attr)
    self.addToGroup(self.methodsR)
    self.addToGroup(self.methods)

    scene.addItem(self)
    self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable, True)
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the text interaction flags of the text items to `Qt.TextEditable`?

Comment: yes, it makes no difference. setTextInteractionFlags(Qt.TextEditable) or setTextInteractionFlags(Qt.TextEditorInteraction). However if I try this on not grouped object - it works fine

Comment: Is there a specific reason for using QGraphicsItemGroup, besides having all items having a common ancestor?

Answer (score 0):

Almost everytime I tried to use QGraphicsGroupItem I ended up by abandoning it, as their behavior (especially when relating to input events) is often unreliable, and based on my research I'm not the only one having faced these issues.

If you only need to "group" all items by a common ancestor, it's much easier and reliable to create a subclass of QGraphicsItem and create items as children of it, which can be accomplished by adding the parent as argument of the constructor, or by using `setParentItem()`. Then, since the abstract QGraphicsItem requires both `boundingRect()` and `paint()` to be implemented, you only need to return the `childrenBoundingRect()` for the first, and just `pass` the second.

In the following rewriting of your code, I took the liberty of reparenting the "labels" to the rectangle they refer to, which makes more sense.
Also, it's usually better to avoid setting relative positions in basic shape items (like QGraphicsRectItem, QGraphicsEllipseItem, etc) unless you really require so, as it would make coordinate referencing more complex than it should: remember that an item is always created at coordinates `(0, 0)`, and when you create a QGraphicsRectItem with `(x, y, width, height)`, the `x` and `y` refer to the *rectangle* of the item, **not** the *position* of the item, which will still be `(0, 0)` until manually changed.

```
class Uml(QGraphicsItem):
    def __init__(self, x, y, scene):
        super().__init__()

        self.headerR = QGraphicsRectItem(0, 0, 70, 30, self)
        self.header = QGraphicsTextItem("header", self.headerR)
        self.header.setTextInteractionFlags(Qt.TextEditorInteraction)

        self.attrR = QGraphicsRectItem(0, 0, 70, 50, self)
        self.attr = QGraphicsTextItem("attributes", self.attrR)
        self.attrR.setY(30)

        self.methodsR = QGraphicsRectItem(0, 0, 70, 50, self)
        self.methods = QGraphicsTextItem("methods", self.methodsR)
        self.methodsR.setY(80)

        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable, True)
        scene.addItem(self)
        self.setPos(x, y)

    def boundingRect(self):
        return self.childrenBoundingRect()

    def paint(self, *args):
        pass
```